# Does $f'(z)=0$ for all $z\in D$ imply $f(z)=$constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

We know from complex analysis that $f'(z)=0,\forall z\in D\implies f(z)=$constant if $D$ is an open connected set.Does $f'(z)=0$ for all $z\in D$ imply $f(z)=$constant for a complex valued function on a complex domain $D\subset \mathbb C$ if the domain is not an open connected set?I think it is not so because I can take $f(z)=1$ if $z\in D_1$ and $f(z)=i$ if $z\in D_2$ where $D=D_1\cup D_2$ and $D_1$ and $D_2$ are disjoint open balls in $\mathbb C$.Does my example work?

Comment: Yes, your example is correct.

Comment: Note that this has not that much to do with complex analysis. The very same problem arises in real analysis. Vanishing derivative implies locally constant, but not necessarily constant as you showed with your counterexample.